# How does Pi overcome WPA2 protection

Tags: wifi

"You will need to configure your wireless adaptor later in Linux but for now it is not necessary"

so NOOBS downloads operating systen using WIFI link to internet WITHOUT me having entered any WPA2 security code.

Nice feature!  Makes life much easier at this stage.

But has left me concerned.

If authors of Pi's boot utilities can obtain wireless access through my internet gateway without any WPA2 security code, then presumably so can anyone else who can get their hands on the appropriate code.  Something which villains seem to find easy to do.

When I set up the Pi for the first time it stuck on "NOOBS is Initialising". Google reveals that this happens if the Ethernet connection is via an internet switch, which was the case. So I placed a nano USB wireless adaptor (new and never previously used), then Noobs was no longer stuck, and offered me choice of downloads, then downloaded the OS with no further requirement for me to input information.

Comment: Welcome to the site. To the best of my knowledge the Pi can't auto-crack WPA2 passcodes and should only be capable of joining open networks or networks you've provided the credentials for. Are you saying that you've never input or otherwise stored a set of network credentials, your network is password protected, and the Pi has still managed to connect to your network and download things?

Comment: As goobering implies what you think happened is not what actually happened.

Comment: @goldilocks Google's giving me no love on the exact phrase 'You will need to configure your...', which is making it tricky to figure out whether that's come from a writeup somewhere (i.e. this is a theoretical situation) or an actual system message. I've never seen it before. Ringing any bells with you?

Comment: @goobering I'm guessing it's been taken out of context because the OP *thinks* the Pi automagically hacked his/her WLAN.   It's ambiguous sort of like "When pigs fly" might seem ambiguous if you weren't sure whether they could or not ;)  Possibly the pigs only fly at night.

Comment: Yes, exactly what goobering said.

Comment: Checked various references, for instance,  "Configuration of the wireless connection is done within Linux, so for now it's enough simply to connect the adapter to the Pi...."  R Pi User Guide  Upton Halfacree

Comment: I'm not sure NOOBS actually downloads the OSs from the net. I thought it was already on the NOOBS SD card. In fact, the Raspberry Pi NOOBS page says "You won’t need network access, and you won’t need to download any special imaging software". I assume you set up WiFi access after the selected OS is installed. Perhaps @priscus misunderstood what was happening...

Comment: Apologies if that is the case, but the commentary said it WAS DOWNLOIADING

Answer (score 1):

"You will need to configure your wireless adaptor later in Linux but for now it is not necessary"

means that you don't need to configure your wireless connection **again** on a Linux distro after NOOBS installs it. NOOBS will automatically *transfer* the WiFi settings into the Linux install.

Needless to say , in most cases a wired connection will auto-configure itself faster and will take precedence over WiFi if available. This will enable you to download things without entering any WiFi keys at all.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected to happen, but NOOBS got stuck on initialising, so I REPLACED the Ethernet patch cable with nano USB WIFI adapter. (Google results said that symptom reported when Ethernet is via a Switch)  Then downloaded OS (allegedly) without requiring me to enter any info.

Comment: Raspbian is still included inside NOOBS and doesn't need to be downloaded. NOOBS lite needs to download everything

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which OS you were installing or which version of NOOBS you were installing from. **NOOBS Lite** requires that all OS's be downloaded. **NOOBS** contains the full Raspbian release, other OS's are downloaded.

The Model 3 can use it's WiFi system after configuration, or a Raspberry Pi dongle can be used for earlier versions.

I suspect you misunderstood what NOOBS was doing. Perhaps the progress messages are vague or misleading...

Edit... The NOOBS [document](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md#wifi-networks) shows the configuration window for WiFi.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with any of these points, but none of them really explain what might be happening here. Can you explain why the NOOBS installation process might stall during a download over an ethernet cable connected to a switch, and why that download would resume after a WiFi dongle is connected?